# Servlets on Tomcat: Requested resource is not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am on Mac OSX. This is my first Servlet. I have Tomcat 8.0.14

I have created a Servlet that simply takes three parameters via HTTP POST method. This 
is my Servlet:

***HelloWorld.java:***

```
package com.hello.world;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String mname = request.getParameter("mname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.println("<center><h1>HelloWorld!<br></h1>");
            out.println("<h2>" + (fname != null ? fname : "") + " "
                               + (mname != null ? mname : "") + " "
                               + (lname != null ? lname : "") + "</h2></center>");

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles properly and I have placed the compiled class file in the default `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes` directory as:

```
/Library/Java/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/hello/world/HelloWorld.class
```

Then I have my ***web.xml*** file as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1"
         metadata-complete="true">

         <servlet>
             <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>com.hello.world.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
         </servlet>

         <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/controller.do</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have placed this file in the default `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/` directory as:

```
/Library/Java/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Then I have my `index.html` as:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="controller.do">
            <center>
                <table>
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td><label for="fname">Firstname:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="textfield" name="fname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td><label for="mname">Middlename:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="textfield" name="mname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td><label for="lname">Lastname:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="textfield" name="lname"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" value="Post this stupid form">
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have placed this file in the default `webapps/ROOT/` directory as:

```
/Library/Java/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/index.html
```

When I type `localhost:8080/index.html`, the HTML loads up and I am able to post the form properly and get the desired output.
This works fine.

But when I create a separate directory named `HelloWorld` and move these three files in it, such than my directory structure becomes like this:

```
/Library/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT
|
|->HelloWorld
    |
    |->index.html
    |->WEB-INF
        | 
        |->web.xml
        |->classes
            |
            |->com
                |->hello
                    |->world
                        |->HelloWorld.class
```

and type `localhost:8080/HelloWorld`, the HTML loads up fine. But when I post the form, it says

```
HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/controller.do

type Status report

message /HelloWorld/controller.do

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem.  Is it because I have created a separate directory? But I think that shouldn't be. I need help. How do I get this working?

Comment: I have tested your code with the same folder structure under tomcat server and it's working fine for me without doing any change.

Comment: Did you restart Apache? And plz never use a try-catch(IOExcption) structure in Servlets, the `doXxx` methods can always throw an `IOException` that are automatically handled by Tomcat

Comment: i restarted it like 100 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have the HelloWorld folder under ROOT, like `webapps/ROOT/HelloWorld/` with a web.xml in  `webapps/ROOT/HelloWorld/WEB-INF/web.xml` and the classes in `webapps/ROOT/HelloWorld/WEB-INF/classes/...`  It won't work like that.

Each folder directly under `webapps` is its own self-contained app that can only have one web.xml active.  So `ROOT` is a webapp that will only read the web.xml found at `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` with the classes in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/...`

If you had another folder `webapps/HelloWorld` it would read the web.xml in  `webapps/HelloWorld/WEB-INF/web.xml`  with the classes in `webapps/HelloWorld/WEB-INF/classes/...`

That's the normal way to do it.

But session is not shared across apps. So doing it that way, root will have its own session, and HelloWorld its own session.

So, if you really need `HelloWorld` to be under root, then you'll have to define your servlet in the web.xml in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` and put your class files in the WEB-INF directly under root: `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/...`  Then you'd have to define the url-pattern in the web.xml as (at least theoretically I think this would work):

```
     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/HelloWorld/controller.do</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```